# I want to access followers of this page, but it is only showing this much of data

Tags: php, fb-graph

I am trying to access the followers/likers of this page but it is showing only this much of data. How can i access all the info of this page.

category    "Utilities"
link            "http://localhost/cricshots/"
name            "cricketshotsofficial"
id          "1996682000635998"

Trying to get the access using this code:

```
$json_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' . $facebook_page_id.'?access_token=' . $access_token ;
```

Expect the output to be the complete details of this page or only the followers of the page

Answer (score 1):

This is an updated and working code snippet which can be used to retrieve Facebook like count of a specific page. To use this code snippet you’ll need a Facebook App ID and Secret Key.

```
<?php
function fbLikeCount($id,$appid,$appsecret){  // $id = Fb Page id
  $json_url ='https://graph.facebook.com/'.$id.'?access_token='.$appid.'|'.$appsecret.'&fields=fan_count';
  $json = file_get_contents($json_url);
  $json_output = json_decode($json);
  //Extract the likes count from the JSON object
  if($json_output->fan_count){
    return $fan_count = $json_output->fan_count;
  }else{
    return 0;
  }
}
echo fbLikeCount('coregenie','___APPID___','___APPSECRET___');
?>
```

Please edit your page name, app id, app secret.

Comment: Showing me this message "(#10) To use 'Page Public Content Access', your use of this endpoint must be reviewed and approved by Facebook. To submit this 'Page Public Content Access' feature for review please read our documentation on reviewable features: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review." @strange

Comment: Facebook Page id

Comment: Showing above msg @strange

Comment: You can use this feature after your FB App is reviewed and approved.

Comment: Read the quidelines here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review to submit app for review